# Pig Latin Translator in Ruby and Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, pig-latin

**PigLatin Kata**

```
PigLatin Kata
   Create a PigLatin class that is initialized with a string
      - detail: The string is a list of words seperated by spaces: 'hello world'
      - detail: The string is accessed by a method named phrase
      - detail: The string can be reset at any time without re-initializing
      - example: PigLatin.new('hello world')

completed (Y|n):

   Translate Method
      Create a translate method that translates the phrase from english to pig-latin.
         - detail: The method will return a string.
         - detail: The empty string will return nil.
         - example: "" translates to nil

completed (Y|n):

      Translate words that start with vowels.
         - detail: Append "ay" to the word if it ends in a consonant.
         - example: "ask" translates to "askay"
         - detail: Append "yay" to the word if it ends with a vowel.
         - example: "apple" translates to "appleyay"
         - detail: Append "nay" to the word if it ends with "y".
         - example: "any" translates to "anynay"

completed (Y|n):

      Translate a word that starts with a single consonant.
         - detail: Removing the consonant from the front of the word.
         - detail: Add the consonant to the end of the word.
         - detail: Append 'ay' to the resulting word.
         - example: "hello" translates to "ellohay"
         - example: "world" translates to "orldway"

completed (Y|n):

      Translate words that start with multiple consonants.
         - detail: Remove all leading consonants from the front of the word.
         - detail: Add the consonants to the end of the word.
         - detail: Append 'ay' to the resulting word.
         - example: "known" translates to "ownknay"
         - example: "special" translates to "ecialspay"

completed (Y|n):

      Support any number of words in the phrase.
         - example: "hello world" translates to "ellohay orldway"
         - detail: Each component of a hyphenated word is translated seperately.
         - example: "well-being" translates to "ellway-eingbay"

completed (Y|n):

      Support capital letters.
         - detail: If a word is captalized, the translated word should be capitalized.
         - example: "Bill" translates to "Illbay"
         - example: "Andrew" translates to "Andreway"

completed (Y|n):

      Retain punctuation.
         - detail: Punctuation marks should be retained from the source to the translated string
         - example: "fantastic!" tranlates to "anfasticfay!"
         - example: "Three things: one, two, three." translates to "Eethray ingsthay: oneyay, otway, eethray."

completed (Y|n):



Congratulations!
- Create a PigLatin class that is initialized with a string                00:03:51
- Create a translate method that translates the phrase from english to p   00:02:09
- Translate words that start with vowels.                                  00:09:24
- Translate a word that starts with a single consonant.                    00:05:13
- Translate words that start with multiple consonants.                     00:01:26
- Support any number of words in the phrase.                               02:48:13
- Support capital letters.                                                 00:10:46
- Retain punctuation.                                                      00:40:26
----------------------------------------------------------------------     --------
Total Time taking PigLatin kata:                                           04:01:27
```

**Specs:**

```
  1 require 'spec_helper'
  2 require 'piglatin'
  3
  4 describe PigLatin do
  5   subject(:piglatin) { PigLatin.new phrase }
  6   let(:phrase) { "hello world" }
  7
  8   describe "new" do
  9     specify { expect { piglatin }.to_not raise_error }
 10   end
 11
 12   describe ".translate" do
 13     let(:phrase) { "" }
 14     its(:translate) { should eq("") }
 15
 16     context "for words that start with vowels" do
 17       context "and end with consonants" do
 18         let(:phrase) { "ask" }
 19         subject(:translate) { piglatin.translate }
 20         it 'appends ay' do
 21           should eq("askay")
 22         end
 23       end
 24       context "and end with vowels" do
 25         let(:phrase) { "apple" }
 26         its(:translate) do should eq("appleyay") end
 27       end
 28       context "and ends with y" do
 29         let(:phrase) { "any" }
 30         its(:translate) { should eq(phrase + "nay") }
 31       end
 32     end
 33
 34     context "words that start with consonants" do
 35       let(:phrase) { "hello" }
 36       its(:translate) { should eq("ellohay") }
 37     end
 38     context "words that start with multiple consonants" do
 39       let(:phrase) { "known" }
 40       its(:translate) { should eq("ownknay") }
 41     end
 42     context "multiple words" do
 43       let(:phrase) { "hello world" }
 44       its(:translate) { should eq("ellohay orldway") }
 45     end
 46     context 'hyphenated words' do
 47       let(:phrase) { "well-being" }
 48       its(:translate) { should eq("ellway-eingbay") }
 49     end
 50     context 'capatalized words' do
 51       let(:phrase) { "Bill" }
 52       its(:translate) { should eq("Illbay") }
 53     end
 54     context 'capatalized words' do
 55       let(:phrase) { "Andrew" }
 56       its(:translate) { should eq("Andreway") }
 57     end
 58     context 'punctuation marks' do
 59       let(:phrase) { "fantastic!" }
 60       its(:translate) { should eq("antasticfay!") }
 61     end
 62     context 'complex phrase' do
 63       let(:phrase) { 'Three things: one, two, three.' }
 64       its(:translate) { should eq('Eethray ingsthay: oneyay, otway, eethray.') }
 65     end
 66   end
 67 end
```

**PigLatin class:**

```
  1 class PigLatin
  2   attr_accessor :phrase
  3   alias :initialize :phrase=
  4
  5   def translate
  6     return "" if @phrase.empty?
  7     @phrase.gsub!(/\w+/) { |word| translate_word(word) }
  8   end
  9
 10   private
 11
 12   def translate_word(word)
 13     # Consonants
 14     word.concat(word.slice!(/^[^aeiou]*/i || ""))
 15     # Vowels
 16     word.gsub!(/y$/, "yn") or word.gsub!(/([aeiou])$/, '\1y')
 17     # Capitalized Words
 18     word.capitalize! if word.downcase!
 19     # Ending
 20     word += 'ay'
 21   end
 22 end
```

Answer (score 3):

The code clearly works, and is very concise. I think that to make it more readable, instead of using comments, you could have expressive method names:

```
def translate_word(word)
  replace_consonants_to_end_of_word(word)

  append_n_to_last_letter_y(word) or append_y_to_last_letter_vowel(word)

  recapitalize(word)

  word += 'ay'
end

def replace_consonants_to_end_of_word(word)
  word.concat(word.slice!(/^[^aeiou]*/i || ""))
end

def append_n_to_last_letter_y(word)
  word.gsub!(/y$/, "yn")
end

def append_y_to_last_letter_vowel(word)
  word.gsub!(/([aeiou])$/, '\1y')
end

def recapitalize(word)
  word.capitalize! if word.downcase!
end
```

Sure, it's a little longer, but I believe it is more readable, and one can appreciate more how you tackled each of the requirements.

Nice code, anyway.